# npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When i am trying to run this command "npm install -g" than it give an error like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWcTa.png)

Comment: Pleas read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Simply you must to set up:

- npm config set proxy http: //proxy.company.com:8080
- npm config set https-proxy http: //proxy.company.com:8080

Visit https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

If don't work it you treat to execute cmd as administrator.